# Java - How to sort objects by type and put them into LinkedLists of that specific type?

Tags: java

so I have a LinkedList of elements witch contains some fields, where my field class extends element, and I need to sort the fields from the LinkedList and put it into another LinkedList of type field so I can call methods specific to the field class, that aren't in element. How would I go about sorting ONLY the field objects into their own LinkedList?

Here's some sample code to demonstrate my issue:

```
for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++){
    element tempElement = e.get(i);
    // if it is a field, add it to the LinkedList of fields
}
```

Any help or feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: If `element` and `field` are class names, then you're not following common Java naming conventions, which state that class names should start with uppercase letter, so they should be `Element` and `Field`. Your question is rather confusing, because a collection contains elements (generic term for objects), and a class contains fields (instance variables), buy you're using those same terms as class names without Uppercase.

Comment: you can use `instanceof` for this, ex: `if(e.get(i) instanceof Field){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know prior that there are some certain types of objects in the list, you could simply iterate through the list, extract objects and insert them in the **proper list**, such as:

```
List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
for(int i=0; i<e.size(); i++)
{
    if (e.get(i) instanceof Field)
    {
        fields.add(e.get(i));
        // or maybe call methods specific to Field objects
        // ((Field) e.get(i)).specificMethod();
    }
}
```

so you'll end up having the list with all objects of type **Field** in the list of elements.
Hope this answers your question.